# Как получить все контакты из таблицы, у которых 2 и более сделок

Tags: django, python-3.x

Вопрос заключается в том, что мне нужно получить все записи(контакты) из таблицы "Contact", у которых сделок больше чем 2, Сделки находятся в таблице Lead и именно в это таблице определяется какому контакту она принадлежит.

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    fio = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)

objects = models.Manager

class Lead(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   price = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   contact_id = models.IntegerField()

objects = models.Manager
```

Предположительный код SQL у меня получается такой(думаю верный):

```
SELECT * FROM Contact c WHERE COUNT( SELECT * FROM Lead l WHERE l.contact_id=c.id ) > 2
```

А мне нужно написать тоже самое используя **методы модели django**:
например используя **Contact.objects.extra(...)**, если нет ничего лучше.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запрос должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
Lead.objects.annotate(counter=Count('contact_id')).filter(counter__gt=2)
```

Немного отойдя от темы, есть смысл добавить внешний ключ:

```
contact_id = models.ForeignKey(Contact)
```

Comment: Спасибо, я изменил запрос так, и всё получилось: Contact.objects.annotate(counter=Count('lead')).filter(counter__gte=2)
И добавил в Lead: contact_id = models.ForeignKey(Contact)